# Blender transparent bsdf not fully transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, transparency

I was trying to add a fire effect to the side of this car. I wanted just the fire to be showing and everything else transparent. I made the node setup. But for some reason, the transparent areas were not 100% transparent. The transparent areas looked a little brighter than the actual area. I thought it was my node setup that was the problem and lost my mind over this. Then I said frick it and plugged in just a transparent shader. To my surprise, with no other node setup connected, just the transparent shader was not in fact fully transparent. So it's definitely nothing to do with my setup.

[image]

I opened up another blender file and made a cube and a plane in front of the cube to test my theory. I was right!

[image]

This time, the transparent shader made the area a little darker. I tried some things people recommended online but nothing worked.

Comment: Is the white really white?

Comment: yes, it is. I can confirm it's not about the node itself cause even if I messed up the original file, in the second image it's a brand new transparent BSDF node.

Comment: Can you include the file?

Comment: I can't confirm your issue with default Scene on my side ... so file with your Cube would be needed to check.

Comment: Just checking the colors in your second screenshot, the color of the _Transparent BSDF_ is R/G/B = 231 instead of 255, so it's not pure white e.g. not fully transparent. So the RGB values are 0.8 instead of 1. It's not a problem of the screenshot, the object color in the display properties is R/G/B = 255.